# How to make a Yii2 GridView responsive?

Tags: gridview, responsive-design, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a usual GridView in Yii2.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'tableOptions' => ['class' => 'table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive'],
        'columns' => [
              'firstName',
              'lastName',   
              [
                 'attribute' => 'verified',
                 'format' => 'html',
                 'value' => function($data){  
                      ....
                  }
              ],
         ]
]); ?>
```

The GridView is not responsive in mobile. How can I make the GridView page responsive?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As it states in [Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables-responsive):

> Create responsive tables by wrapping any `.table` in `.table-responsive`

So just wrap your widget in

```
<div class="table-responsive">
// GridView here
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the **right** option.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
'tableOptions' => [
    'class' => 'table table-striped',
],
'options' => [
    'class' => 'table-responsive',
],
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
```